# keyboard appears and resizes toolbar

Tags: android, keyboard, toolbar, android-custom-view

After many recommendations to use Toolbar instead of Actionbar I finally made the switch. Everything is working fine except the following issue. When the user clicks the EditText the toolbar view messes up and resizes.

**How the Toolbar looks without keyboard**

[image]

**How the Toolbar looks when the keyboard comes up**

[image]

I would like for the both the toolbar and the keyboard to appear fully when the keyboard comes up.

**When I used ActionBar, I used the following settings to make it work
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"**

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/CCLL"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:background="#F1F1F1"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#3DA1FE"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".46"
        >



    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".09">

        <ListView
            android:isScrollContainer="false"
            android:stackFromBottom="true"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:id="@+id/messagesLV"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"/>

    </LinearLayout>




    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".45"
        android:background="@drawable/livefeedgradient"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/addimgbtn"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.1"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@mipmap/grayaddimage" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/messageET"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:lines="5"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
            android:hint="Enter your Message...">
        </EditText>


        <ImageButton
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/sendbtn"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@mipmap/graysend" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the xml ?

Comment: Add minHeight in your Toolbar - android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"

Comment: Why do you need to use `android:layout_weight=".46"` with Toolbar. When the parent LinearLayout is resized because of soft keyboard, your Toolbar will also be resized.

Comment: Then what should I set the weight for the toolbar? @ReyPham

Comment: I think you can remove `android:layout_weight` and change `android:layout_height` of Toolbar to `wrap_content`.

Comment: @ReyPham warp_content filled up my entire screen with the toolbar but giving it a fixed value of 50dp did the work. But the edittext can't be seen at all when the keyboard appears now

Comment: Your EditText also used `android:layout_weight` so it has same problem as Toolbar.

Comment: Haha! Wrap_content did the work! You're a hero @ReyPham ! Thanks a lot man :)

Comment: But isn't there anyway I can use the weight so it can automatically resize depending on whatever the size of the screen is for different users? @ReyPham